# How can I shorten (encode) a thirteen-digit number to a short string of numbers, letters, and punctuation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to find a way to shorten a thirteen-digit number while retaining its ability to be hand-typed. That is, I like a way to turn something like this: `2935497213884`into this: `mY==!2N`. What would be the best way of doing this in Javascript? I looked into base64 encoding, and LZW compression, but most of the algorithms I found actually made the string longer instead of shorter.

I consider as hand-typable the characters: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz01234567890~`!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}|;:'",./<>?:"

Comment: Can you explain your question better? Why don't you just create a variable containing the value you want?

Comment: How did you get to `mY==!2N`? What character set to you consider hand-typable?

Comment: Why not use another base for numeral system (for example hexadecimal or numeral system with base 26 etc...) ? It will be easy to convert between two numeral systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["large number array compression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596494/large-number-array-compression)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/93mbh8qj/):

```
var test = [2935497213884]
alert(encodeNums(test))
alert(decodeNums(encodeNums(test)))
```

You can set hand-typable characters in 'encodable' variable.